# python: from .folder import VS from floder import

Tags: python

My folder structure looks like the following:

```
/main
    /abc
        __init__.py
    start.py
```

in the **init**.py file i defined a function:

`def pprint():
    print('123')`

I try to import the function at the start.py
`from .abc import pprint` works on linux,
`from abc import pprint` works on windows.
Is there a good practice that I could write this part of the code that indifference of the OS?

Comment: "from abc import pprint" should work in linux too. Can you please check if python version on linux and windows environment is same ?

Comment: @PhagunBaya linux is python 3.5 and windows is python 3.6, I can't update linux version but I could down grade the windows and see if they both behave the same on 3.5

Comment: OK. I was suspecting that python version on windows is 2.7. `from .abc import pprint` should work in windows as well.